# Using Cognito Admin API to create users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have created a user pool in Cognito as 'Only allow administrators to create users' . Now I wish to add users from my react application, but I am failing to understand which APIs to call to add users and to force change password for the first time.

Also, does AWS Amplify provide us with any APIs to use when creating users as Administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AdminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) API to create a user. 
AWS amplify has the following demo code for authenticating users created by admin who need password change:

```
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        // User authentication was successful
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        // User authentication was not successful
    },

    mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
        // MFA is required to complete user authentication.
        // Get the code from user and call
        cognitoUser.sendMFACode(mfaCode, this)
    },

    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
        // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new
        // password and required attributes, if any, to complete
        // authentication.

        // the api doesn't accept this field back
        delete userAttributes.email_verified;

        // Get these details and call
        cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, this);
    }
});
```